# Laptop freezes during install of Ubuntu 15.10 from usb

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, acer

I'm trying to install 64bit Ubuntu 15.10 from a usb on this laptop:

ACER Aspire One Cloudbook 14" (A01-431-C2Q8)
Intel® Celeron™ Processor N3050 (integrated Intel graphics with shared memory)
Memory: 2 GB
Storage: 32 GB eMMC

I get the Ubuntu loader and then it freezes.

I previously installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with no problems.

Thanks for any suggestions. This is my first venture into Linux.

Update: I switched to UEFI in the BIOS and installed Ubuntu 15.10 without issue, but then could not boot ('no bootable drive'). So I have switched back to legacy BIOS and am back with the issue of freezing during installation.

Update 2: Got through installation by using `nomodeset` in the menu options. But upon reboot the purple desktop just appears to flash repeatedly, and I can get no further.

Comment: I have the same problem with an old Sempron based machine  http://askubuntu.com/questions/750704/early-machine-advent-7105-sempron-3000-wont-install-15-10-or-16-04-ok-with

Answer (score 1):

The boot flags you need to boot are

```
edd=off noapic modprobe.blacklist=pinctrl_cherryview
```

APIC on that laptop likes to throw a fit when booting, and Ubuntu uses the Cherryview graphics for the chipset, which doesn't work either.